# Angular - Repeat value on select Option

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

I have a select, where the user's servers are rendered. Each server has several security groups. I need to show the user on select, only the server that does not have that security group. However, in my select, it is repeating the name of the server for each different security group.

Example: I have the server test01 it has the security groups: novo09, default, relow.

When I select the security group hello01, I want to show the server test01 only once in select, and not 2 times, it is showing 2 times because I have 2 groups already included in server = novo09, relow.

server payload:

```
{id: "b9c7e32a-bf99-4250-83cb-13523f9c1604", name: "test01", flavor: {…}, securityGroups: [{name: 'relow'}, {name: 'Novo09'} ]}
```

My component code:

```
public selectedGroupName: string = '';
ngOnInit(): void {

    let counter = 0;
    forkJoin(
      this.serverService.getServer(),
      this.securityGroupService.getSecurityGroups())
      .pipe(takeWhile(() => this.alive),
      concatMap((data) => {
        this.servers = data[0].map((item) => ({
          ...item,
          securityGroups: this.serverService.getServerById(item.id)
            .pipe(map(server => server["security_groups"]))
        }))
        this.securityGroups = data[1].map((item) => ({
          ...item,
          expanded: false,
        }))
        return this.servers.map((server) => server.securityGroups);
      }), concatMap(items => items))
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
        this.servers[counter].securityGroups = data.filter(group => group.name !== 'default');
        counter++;
    })

    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      server: new FormControl('')
    })
  }
public openAttachModal(content, securitGroupName: string) {
    this.selectedGroupName = securitGroupName;
}
```

My Html code:

```
      <ng-container *ngFor="let group of securityGroups">
 <div class="user-info__basic">
                <h5 class="mb-0">{{group.name}}</h5>
              </div>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ngbTooltip="Attach Group" triggers="hover"
              (click)="openAttachModal(attachModal, group.name)"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
</ng-container>

 <ng-container *ngFor="let server of servers">
          <ng-container *ngFor="let secGroup of server.securityGroups">
            <ng-container *ngIf="secGroup.name !== selectedGroupName">
              <option [value]="server.id">
                {{server.name}}
              </option>
            </ng-container>
          </ng-container>
          <ng-container *ngIf="server.securityGroups.length == 0">
            <option [value]="server.id">
              {{server.name}}
            </option>
          </ng-container>
        </ng-container>
```

image result of select
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJFmu.jpg

Comment: I don't understand something... Your data model is a server has security groups but the user is going to select the security group first and then the server? Wouldn't the opposite make more sense? Anyway I think you can achieve what you want in several ways. For example, when the user selects the security group, you can trigger an event and generate the list of unique servers. Another solution is when you receive the data, you could build the opposite model, that is, a map where each security group has the list of servers that should be shown depending on the security group selected.

Comment: @Isaac 
Hello

Unfortunately yes, I need to go to the security group screen to select the group, and show all the servers that do not have that security group, in order to include the same in the server. However, my problem is that ta rendering the server 2 times. Because the server has 2 security groups that are different from the selected security group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the user selects the security group, you could trigger an event to extract the list of servers where that security group is not present. Something like:

```
const servers = servers.filter(server => !server.securityGroups.find(secGroup => secGroup.id === selectedSecurityGroup.id));
// Where selectedSecurityGroup is the security group the user selected
```

And you could avoid adding a server twice:

```
servers = servers.filter((server, index, self) => self.indexOf(server) === index);
```

This filter will keep only the first instance of each server.

Comment: Thank you Isaac. This code worked perfectly. \o/